Is it possible to create a rocky moon with high volcanic activity but that has underground water?
I am creating a moon for my gas giant, I am going to give the data and a little more context but first I need to make it clear to everyone that there is no life on this moon and I do not plan that, because there is already a habitable planet and only I'm doing the solar system, well here's the data
Star:

Mass: 1.05 solar mass

Density: 0.965 solar density

Radius: 1.03 solar radius

Luminosity: 1.23 solar luminosity

Temperature: 5989 K

Star class: G0.1V


Planet:

Mass: 717 earth mass

Density: 0.98 g/cm3

Radius: 15.8 earth radius

Distance from its star: 51.8 AU


Moon:

Mass: 0.98 moon mass

Density: 1.7 g/cm3

Radius: 1.24 moon radius

Distance from its planet: 262935 Km


And now that it is done I am going to give the more detailed context, well when I made this moon I thought it would be something like Io, a moon with high volcanic activity but let's say that when I made it I saw that it was very similar to Io so I ask if It is possible to make it have underground water that makes it create bright patterns when there are eruptions, apart from the fact that the lava instead of being sulfur could be silicate lava with the water deposits, although I don't know if it is possible or if it makes sense

More than possible, I would say water is needed if you want high volcanic activity, as water will act as a lubricant and ease the flow of magma, apart from making explosions more likely, due to the vapor pressure.

Ok and a question, having that detail, would the satellite change another color? Because I know that it is like that because of the sulfur while it has silicate lava and with the ice, what color would that give it?

@ Idon'tknow That is highly dependent on the actual composition of the moon. It can be almost anything depending on what its made of.
